# Auto refresh browser on save for Grails project?

Tags: eclipse, grails, intellij-idea, less

I am working on Grails 3 project and I cannot find a way to auto-refresh browser upon save LESS/SASS files and HTML/CSS files and Groovy and GSP files. Assume I have chrome browser window opened to my application page. For quicker development it should refresh automatically when I make a change and save any of the mentioned file types in my project. Eclipse based solution is preferred but IntelliJ IDEA Community edition may be considered or other open source but well maintained and stable solution that works with  Grails/Gradle projects.

FYI I am using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sublime Text you can install the following plugin: https://github.com/gcollazo/BrowserRefresh-Sublime

It adds a key binding to refresh your browser on save. But this would mean starting/stopping your server using some other method. I prefer cmd line or just a terminal screen than a heavy IDE for Grails.